# Objective C: Initializing NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a simple block of code that needs to set an NSString as one thing or another.  In it's most basic form, it looks like this:

```
if (conditionMet){
   NSString *outputString=[NSString stringWithString:@"A"];
} else {
   NSString *outputString=[NSString stringWithString:@"B"];
}
return outputString;
```

But, I'm getting a "Use of undeclared identifier 'outputString'" error.  What is a better way to do this?

I understand this is a pretty basic question, so any quick pointers on how to do this would be terrific.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about ?

```
NSString *outputString;
if (conditionMet){
   outputString=@"A";
} else {
   outputString=@"B";
}
return outputString;
```

You need to learn about [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29)

Shorter version :

`return conditionMet ? @"A" : @"B" ;`

It's called [ternary condition](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#The_Ternary_Operator)

Comment: Or (even more readable perhaps): `NSString *outputString = conditionMet ? @"A" : @"B";`

Comment: OK, perfect.  I was under the incorrect impression that mutable things needed to be set to their initial values as soon as they were declared, so this clears things up!  Thanks!

Comment: `NSString` are not mutables. In general, otherwise explicitly stated (e.g.. `NSMutableString, NSMutableArray`...etc), objects are not mutables.

Comment: Whoops, misspell:  "... _im_mutable things needed to be set..."

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are declaring and defining it within the if else blocks. They are local to that and ARC will release them by the end of the block.

The way to do it is to declare it outside the if-else block. You can the just define the string within and you'll still have a valid NSString object at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *outputString 
if (conditionMet){
  outputString=[NSString stringWithString:@"A"];
} else {
  outputString=[NSString stringWithString:@"B"];

}
return outputString;
```

Comment: Just assign the string literal directly to `outputString`. There is no need to call `stringWithString`. See the selected answer.